# How to display(not download) files on a webpage in php?

Tags: php, pdf

I am showing a list of files on a webpage. Files may be of any type like pdf,doc,excel,txt etc.
What i want is when some one click on an item of the list then that file should be displayed in another tab. I dont want to download the file. I just want them to be visible so that user can read it.
I try this using php for pdf files i am able to get the plain content of the file but i want a viewer type of thing. 
Can i achieve this?
If yes can i achieve this in php?
If yes then how?

Thanks and Regards 
Sumit Rathore

Comment: Embed your PDF output- google embed tag

Comment: @Nightfirecat no that code depend upon browser's capability in firefox that will ask whether to save or download the document but in chrome it directly download the document. I want a to create a viewer that will show all types of files not only pdf.

Comment: Which PDF library are you using?

Comment: this is my code `<?php
$filename= "www.dedoimedo.com-apache-web-server-lm.pdf";
$content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -');
echo "$content";
?>
`

Comment: @scrowler i tried this `<html>
        <body>
                <embed src="www.dedoimedo.com-apache-web-server-lm.pdf">
        </body>
</html` but it says additional plufin requires. What should i do?

Comment: @SumitRathore You should clarify your question. The code provided in that question and its answers will instruct browsers to display a PDF using whatever native plugin or renderer they come with.

Comment: @Nightfirecat you are right. I tried many solutions but all required browser's support. Either i try to create a image of each page and then display it or will give download link in case of non supporting browser.

Answer (score 1):

downloading or viewing any file in browser depends on browser setting.

for example in firefox in Options - > Applications Tab you can change state of reading a file that can be downloading or viewing.

now, for display a file to visitor best solution is creating a special php or flash app.

Good Luck.

see http://view.samurajdata.se/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <embed src="www.dedoimedo.com-apache-web-server-lm.pdf">
        </body>
    </html>
```

This code is working in google chrome but not in other browsers.